# Doctrine2 memory leak on fetching data

Tags: php, memory-leaks, doctrine-orm

I need to process large a set of data with Doctrine, but I faced with memory leaks in Doctrine2 and I can't figure out what else I can do to avoid it.
I simplified the code as much as possible, but even this simple code causes memory leak (please note I don't do any inserts, updates, flushes, etc. Only select data)

```
    gc_enable();

    $conn = $em->getConnection();
    $conn->getConfiguration()->setSQLLogger(null); // disabling Logger

    $batchSize = 10000;

    for ($i=0; $i<$batchSize*10; $i+=$batchSize) {
        echo "#".$i." - ";

        $query = $em->createQuery('
            SELECT
                p
            FROM
                Application\Entity\Product p
            WHERE
                p.id > :id
            ORDER BY
                p.id ASC
        ')
            ->setParameter('id', $i)
            ->setMaxResults($batchSize);

        $query->useQueryCache(false);
        $query->useResultCache(false);

        $products = $query->getResult();

        // trying to clear all that is possible
        $query = null;
        $products = null;

        $em->clear();
        $em->close();

        gc_collect_cycles();

        $mu = memory_get_usage(true);
        echo "Memory: ".number_format($mu/1000000, 2)." Mb\n";
    }
```

Here's the output:

```
#0 - Memory: 87.29 Mb
#10000 - Memory: 94.37 Mb
#20000 - Memory: 100.66 Mb
#30000 - Memory: 110.36 Mb
#40000 - Memory: 119.01 Mb
#50000 - Memory: 123.99 Mb
#60000 - Memory: 131.07 Mb
#70000 - PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 40 bytes) in ...\vendor\doctrine\orm\lib\Doctrine\ORM\UnitOfWork.php on line 2615
```

What else can I try to perform to get rid of this leak?

Doctrine ORM 2.4.6
Doctrine DBAL 2.4.2

Comment: Did you try array hydration? `getResult(Doctrine\ORM\Query::HYDRATE_ARRAY);`, this way you'll get associative arrays instead of objects, should use less memory.

Comment: It uses less memory, but also causes memory leaks

Comment: Data uses memory, this much data uses a lot of memory - I wouldn't call that a leak.

Comment: I clear all the data, but  memory is not cleared, look at the code. What is it if not a memory leak?

Comment: See this thread i hope your problem might be solved : https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/symfony-devs/0Ez-TpsC3I0

Comment: I found the  reason, it was caused by event listener which is called for given entity every time